# Deploying JAX-RS Servlet with constructor parameters

Tags: jax-rs, java-7, constructor-injection

I am developing a JAX-RS servlet that adds an item to a queue using a POST method.

```
public class ServletResource extends Application {

    private BlockingQueue<Item> queue;

    public ServletResource(BlockingQueue<Item> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void doPost(Item item) {
        queue.put(item);
    }
}
```

My problem is that using ResourceConfig, for deploying the Servlet in Tomcat, I can't pass the constructor parameters because ResourceConfig works at class level.

#### Main Method

```
BlockingQueue<CAPAlert> alertQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(5000);

tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setPort(servletPort);

File base = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
Context rootCtx = tomcat.addContext("", base.getAbsolutePath());

ServletContainer servlet = new ServletContainer(
                                        new ResourceConfig(
                                                ServletResource.class));

Tomcat.addServlet(rootCtx, "Servlet", servlet);
rootCtx.addServletMapping(servletPath, "Servlet");
tomcat.start();
```

**SOLUTION 1**: I found this solution:

```
ServletContainer servlet = new ServletContainer(
                                new ResourceConfig().register(
                                        new ServletResource(queue)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally get the next solution:

```
ServletContainer servlet = new ServletContainer(
                                new ResourceConfig().register(
                                        new ServletResource(queue)));
```